# Is it correct to use a semi-colon or a colon in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Would it be better to use a colon or semi-colon in the following sentence:

> That being said, the ontological argument fails to do what it intends; it does not prove the existence of God a priori.
>
> That being said, the ontological argument fails to do what it intends: it does not prove the existence of God a priori.

Answer (score 1):

From a copyediting perspective, I think that different optimum ways of framing your sentence are available, depending on whether you want to punctuate it with a semicolon, a colon, or neither.

If you want to separate the two main clauses with a semicolon, you might use this wording:

> That being said, the ontological argument does not accomplish its goal; it does not prove the existence of God a priori.

If you want to separate the two main clauses with a colon, you might use this wording:

> That being said, the ontological argument fails to do what it intends: prove the existence of God a priori.

If you want to merge the two main clauses with minimal punctuation, you might use this wording:

> That being said, the ontological argument fails to prove the existence of God a priori.

In the version punctuated with a semicolon, you essentially dedicate the first part of the sentence to saying that the argument fails, and then dedicate the second part of the sentence to stating what the argument fails to do. The sentence is thus constructed like overlapping shingles on a roof—a design that puts a premium on helping the reader manage the overlapping portion of the two statements. In my view, the wording "the argument does not succeed; it does not do X" presents the overlapping idea more clearly than does the wording "the argument fails to achieve success; it does not do X."

In the version punctuated with a colon, however, ending the first clause with "its goal" or "what it intends" invites an immediate statement of what that goal or intention was—without any repetition of the fact that the argument doesn't succeed. Here there is no need for overlap; you can simply say that the argument didn't achieve its goal, punctuate with a colon, and then state what the goal was.

In the version with merged clauses, you dispense with the buildup to a midsentence punctuation break, and instead combine the two main clauses of the original construction into a single smooth-flowing statement. This condensed form of expression is great if you face severe space constraints and need to say things as succinctly as possible in order to avoid having to cut useful information elsewhere in the text. The resulting sentence is easy to comprehend, and it says in 15 words what the semicolon-bearing sentence said in 21 words and the colon-bearing sentence said in 18 words.

Of course, one person's needless clutter is another person's measured style. No matter which approach you take, if you and your readers reach the end of the article with a shared understanding of your ideas and with a sense of satisfaction about how you got there, you have done your job well.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the headline question itself: Yes. As Sheridan Baker put it in *The Complete Stylist,* the semicolon is like a red traffic light while the colon is a green one. Since what precedes the break raises the question of what the intention was, a colon might be preferable as directing the reader forward to the answer to that question.